# Invalid Object Name SSISDB.dbo.DDLEvents

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am using Sql server 2017.I have admin access to Server.When I am trying to create a role and provide read to any Db I am getting the error message.

### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

### Create failed for User '\XXXXX.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

---

Invalid object name 'SSISDB.dbo.DDLEvents'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 208)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=14.00.3238&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=208&LinkId=20476

---

BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------.

Note::while providing admin access this error does not occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error comes from a trigger.
Find the trigger, fix the underlying error by debugging the code in the trigger or disable the trigger and the error will go away.

Comment: Yes It was a trigger defined at db level and associated table was missing